# Is it possible to not have any associated text with a Smart GWT ComboBoxItem?

Tags: java, gwt, user-interface, dictionary, smartgwt

Pretty self-explanatory. I want to just have the combo box without any text outside of it. I just want the physical box.

However, maybe there's a better/smarter way to do what I'm wanting to do that might avoid this entirely. I have a map of values, essentially. In a ListGrid, for each row, I have one column as the key and another column as a combo box of the values which the user can select. I then use the combination of these values to add to a search query.

Right now, I can set the title to "" but that still leaves some spaces and the colon and that's kind of ugly. I've scanned the long method list a few times but don't see anything that might help me out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setShowTitle(false)`, which is described this way "Should we show a title cell for this formItem?". It is common method for all form items.